# Is there an expression in `R` for "output of the last command"?

Tags: r

In Mathematica, the output of the last expression can be accessed using the symbol `%`. 
In particular, one can do the following in Mathematica:

```
1+2
% / 3
```

This will return the output `1`, because the output of the first expression is 3, and `3/3 = 1`.

Is there an equivalent functionality in `R`?

Comment: Ideally, it would be tied to the current environment, so it should work in a sourced script but not leak outside a function. If that's not possible, interactively at the console is certainly better than not having it at all.

Answer (score 26):

Here you go. Try `? .Last.value` to learn more

```
1 + 2
.Last.value /3
```